Is $1+x \approx \frac{1}{(1+x)^{n-1}} \exp(nx)$ true for large $n$?
Sorry in advance for the odd title but I didn't know how to title this. I am asking this in the context of a physics exercise I was doing. There, the solution basically states that:
$$ P(T)= [E-T]^{(3N-5)/2} = E^{(3N-5)/2} \left[1 - \frac{T\cdot((3N-5)/2)}{E\cdot((3N-5)/2)}\right]^{((3N-5)/2)} $$
And since $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n \rightarrow \exp(x)$, we can let $n=(3N-5)/2$ and write:
$$ P(T) \approx E^{(3N-5)/2} \exp\left[-\frac{T(3N-5)/2}{E}\right] $$
But if this logic is correct, can't we just define $f(x) = 1+x$, and as well write that:
$$ f(x) = x+1 = \frac{1}{(x+1)^{n-1}} \left(1 + \frac{nx}{n}\right)^n$$
Which for large $n$ is supposed to result in:
$$ f(x) \approx \frac{1}{(x+1)^{n-1}} \exp(nx) $$
I feel like the latter is obviously not true, just by plotting a graph in GeoGebra. Since, I am basically letting $n\rightarrow \infty$ and still having it in the expression itself. But is this not exactly what the first part is doing? How can $n=(3N+5)/2$ go to infinity, while still having $N$ somehow still be part of the expression.

You mean in the f(x)=1+x? if so yeah

I don't see any errors? I take out the E term, and multiply top/bottom of the second term inside the exponent by (3N-5)/2

Those are constants, I meant that parentheses as a multiplication

Ah I see, well then its easier. You would then need something like $1 \ll n \ll E^2/T^2$ for this approximation to hold. For example if one is only interested in the region around $T=0$ then this might be a good approximation there.
